# PHP XML addChild() not working

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm working on project, one of its functions is to add data to `XML` file that will be extracted later, the extracting part is working well but not the adding part.
I created a new `php` file that contains the code of `XML` adding part, but still not working. 
Here is the `php` file:

```
<?
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
$msg = $xml->addChild('msg');
$msg->addChild('name', 'newName');
$msg->addChild('text', 'myText');
?>
```

Here is the `test.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<msgs>

</msgs>
```

The page shows no php error and the `xml` still the same.
I have been looking for solution for hours but couldn't find. Please help!

Comment: a) Do you use [SimpleXMLElement::asXML($filename)](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) somewhere in that script? b) Does your php instance recognize [the short tag `<?`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)?

Comment: Short open tag is enabled, but i didn't used asXML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simplexml_load_file() returns a SimpleXMLElement to which you're adding elements, you now need to serialise that instance back to a file:

```
$msg->asXML('output.xml');
```

Or if you just want to capture the XML as a string:

```
$xmlString = $msg->asXML();
```

Comment: Yes, you answered while i was writing my answer, thanks anyway :D

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that it does what its supposed to do but not saving, adding this `$xml->asXML('test.xml');` to the end of php  will make it save in the XML file. Found it by reading the filename part of `asXML` doc. here [asXML()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php)